# Running different setTimeouts in a sequence

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, settimeout

I have an array of different 'no. of mins' and I'd like to do a countdown for them one after another:

```
const steps = [{
    label: "Label1",
    time: 4
  },
  {
    label: "Label2",
    time: 2
  },
  {
    label: "Label3",
    time: 1
  }
];

function countdownTimer(time) {

  setTimeout(function () {

    console.log("DONE");

  }, parseInt(time + "000"));
}

function start() {

  steps.forEach(function (step) {
    countdownTimer(step.time);
  });

}
```

However, as with the nature of setTimeout, they all seem to be running at the same time, with the shortest time displaying first.

How do I make setTimeout to run them in sequence, that is, display 4, 2, then 1?

This is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/yqqMVX

Comment: Pass index of each timer in `countdownTimer(step.time, index)` and use this as time for `setTimeout`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/legenjerry/pen/jppBZw?editors=1111

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBBpRZ ?

Answer (score 2):

Your function should wait fora count down timer to finish before starting another, so `forEach` won't work. `forEach` will work only if you are adding the times of the previous object to the current timer, which seems a little bit too much. Just wait for each timer to finish, then start the next one. Use a callback for that:

```
function countdownTimer(obj, callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log(obj.label + ": DONE");
        callback();                                   // when the current cound down is done call callback to start the next one
    }, parseInt(obj.time + "000"));
}

var start = (function () {                            // wrapping in an IIFE to not pollute the global scope with the index variable. You can get rid of it if you want
    var index = 0;                                    // since we are not using a regular loop nor forEach, we need an index to keep track of the current step
    return function next() {                          // this function is called for each step
        if(index < steps.length) {                    // it check if there still a step in the array steps
            countdownTimer(steps[index], next);       // if so it starts its count down timer, telling it to call next once it finished
            index++;
        }
    };
})();
```

**Example:**

```js
const steps = [ { label: "Label1",  time: 4 }, { label: "Label2", time: 2 }, { label: "Label3", time: 1 } ];

function countdownTimer(obj, callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log(obj.label + ": DONE");
        callback();
    }, parseInt(obj.time + "000"));
}

var start = (function () {
    var index = 0;
    return function next() {
        if(index < steps.length) {
            countdownTimer(steps[index], next);
            index++;
        }
    };
})();

console.log("Starting...");
start();
```

Comment: This is nice. I like it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could just have the timer call the function when it's done and pass a parameter for the next index:

```js
const steps = [{label: "Label1",time: 4},{label: "Label2",time: 2},{label: "Label3",time: 1}];

function countdownTimer(i) {
  if (i >= steps.length) return 
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("DONE WITH", steps[i].label);
    countdownTimer(i + 1)
  }, steps[i].time * 1000);    
}

countdownTimer(0)
```

If you need to call `countdownTimer` from a loop you can keep track of the accumulated time and add it to the next call:

```js
const steps = [{label: "Label1",time: 4},{label: "Label2",time: 2},{label: "Label3",time: 1}];

function countdownTimer(time) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("DONE");
  }, time * 1000);
}

function start() {
  let time = 0                         // keep track of time
  steps.forEach(function(step) {
    countdownTimer(step.time + time);  // add it to call
    time += step.time                  // increase for next call
  }); 
}
start()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the modern ES6 way of async/await you can use the following snippet

```js
const steps = [
 {
  label: "Label1",
  time: 4
 },
 {
  label: "Label2",
  time: 2
 },
 {
  label: "Label3",
  time: 1
 }
];

const wait = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms)
    });
};

const start = async () => {
    const startTime = performance.now();

    // use ES6 iterator of the steps array and loop (iterate) over it
    // destructuring is used to obtain index and step
    // for loop is used since .forEach is not awaiting for the callback
    for (const [index, step] of steps.entries()) {
        // await the callback of the wait function
        // and console.log resolved statement
        console.log(`${step.label} done in ${await wait(step.time * 1000)} ms`);
    }

    console.log(`Done in ${performance.now() - startTime}`);
};

start();
```

I'm using a for loop and not forEach, since the last one is not awaiting for the callback.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it

```js
 const output = document.getElementById("result");
 const steps = [
    {
        label: "Label1",
        time: 1
    },
    {
        label: "Label2",
        time: 2
    },
    {
        label: "Label3",
        time: 3
    }
];
const processStep = (step) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!step) { resolve(false); }
    let timeout = parseInt(step.time + "000");
    setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log("DONE", timeout);
        output.innerHTML = "Step " + step.label + " completed after " + step.time + " seconds";
        resolve(step);
    }, timeout);
  });
};
const processSteps = (steps) => {
  let currentStep = steps.shift();
  if (!currentStep) { return ; }
  console.log("processing step", currentStep);
  processStep(currentStep).then(() => {
    processSteps(steps);
  });
};

processSteps(steps);
```

```html
 <section id="result"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using `async await`

```js
const steps = [{
    label: "Label1",
    time: 4
  },
  {
    label: "Label2",
    time: 2
  },
  {
    label: "Label3",
    time: 1
  }
];

// I added `label` parameter to make it easier to see it works
function countdownTimer(time, label) {

  // need to make it as promise function for `await` to work later
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function () {

        console.log(`${label} DONE`);
        resolve(); // resolve the promise

      }, parseInt(time + "000"));
  });
}

// specify async because we use await inside the loop
async function start() {
  for (const step of steps) {
    await countdownTimer(step.time, step.label);
  };
}

start();
```